# Visual Studio 2012 Express Acting Very Strange

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, import, com, ado

Writing a program, using COM ADO library.  Everything is working fine, all as it should be.  Then low and behold I need to use a function from the ADOX library too.   So I add the necessary #import command for ADOX and the compiler generated header throws over a 100 errors.

My import statements are

```
#import "msado15.dll" rename("EOF", "EndOfFile")
#import "msadox.dll" no_namespace
```

Note that I lifted those statements straight out of MSDN example, located here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676148%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Now I discovered that if I add a using command, it sort of works.

```
#import "msado15.dll" rename("EOF", "EndOfFile")
#import "msadox.dll" no_namespace
using namespace ADODB;
```

The above will compile and my program works as it should.   However, it screws up Visual Studio's contextual visualization.  All the type definitions are displaying in black instead of blue and has the red squiggly error indicator underlining it.  Mouse over context help says "undefined identifier" even though it will compile fine.  And you cant get the type information menu or definition by right clicking on the text.

What is going on here?

Thanks

Comment: ***However, it screws up Visual Studio's contextual visualization. All the type definitions are displaying in black instead of blue and has the red squiggly error indicator underlining it.*** Remember that Intellisense is a separate partial compiler. It does not always get it's suggestions right or agree with the compiler in Visual Studio.

Comment: try adding `rename_namespace` or no_namespace to the first, and try "rebuild all" which may fix the contextual help.

Comment: When importing a type library, you should always refresh the cache of IntelliSense manually. To do this, right click on your project and select "Rescan Solution".